# Error: "xcrun: error: unable to find utility "docsetutil", not a developer tool or in PATH" while creating documentation

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, xcode9.3, appledoc

I am using [appledoc](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc) to generate Apple documentation for my framework.

It seems that after upgrading to Xcode 9.3 it has stopped working, giving me the following error:

```
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "docsetutil", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

I have looked at the known issue: https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc/issues/628

Which states that Xcode doesn't have `docutils` any more.

I have also tried with Xcode 9.4.1 and it's still not working.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

According to answer from @x43x61x69 in your GitHub link :

> Seems not just docsetutil was removed but DADocSetAccess.framework as well. 
>   Tested with options:
>   --create-html \
>   --no-create-docset \
>   --no-install-docset \
>   --no-publish-docset \
>   which can create htmls w/o error on Xcode 9.3 GM.

At least for generating html documents it seems to be working in my case. I have tested on XCode 9.4.1

Answer (score 0):

you should select Xcode Command line tool
by opening Xcode prefrences->Locations tab ->
select your current command-line tool from the spinner
then try again
[image]

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted. It is what helped me. Thanks!