# Error: “xcrun: error: unable to find utility ”docsetutil“, not a developer tool or in PATH” while creating documentation

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, apple-documentation

I am using appledoc to generate Apple documentation for my framework.

It seems that after upgrading to Xcode 11.2.1 it has stopped working, giving me the following error:

xcrun: error: unable to find utility "docsetutil", not a developer tool or in PATH

please give me any solution

Comment: Did you fix your xcode-select path?

Comment: Open Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Select your Xcode version from the dropdown(11.2.1) and exit Xcode did this one But Still not working

Comment: OK, I did a quick google and it appears that `docsetutil` went away a long time ago: https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc/issues/628

Comment: I would also suggest this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51076094/error-xcrun-error-unable-to-find-utility-docsetutil-not-a-developer-tool